# Как удалить из каждой строки в списке два последних символа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например:

```
lst1 = ['wer12', 'rtgdf12', 'werfd12']
```

Как сделать так чтобы получилось:

```
lst1 = ['wer','rtgdf','werfd']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так через генераторы:

```
lst1 = ['wer12', 'rtgdf12', 'werfd12']
lst1 = [str[:-2] for str in lst1]
print(lst1)
```

Comment: Это list comprehension (не уверен что есть русский перевод). Генератор это круглые скобочки.

Comment: Есть генераторы списков, словарей и множеств. Пруф:  http://pep8.ru/doc/dive-into-python-3/5.html

Comment: Похоже проблемы перевода. Под генератором в python обычно понимаю [это](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), а это как [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Не знал что у нас это тоже называют генератором.

Comment: Возможно, спасибо за ссылку, ознакомлюсь.

Comment: Это [списковое включение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать срезы, для получения части строки.

```
lst1 = list( map( lambda x : x[:-2], lst1 ) )
```

lambda x: x[:-2] --- анонимная фукнция, которая возращает строку без последних 2х символов.

map --- применит функцию к каждому элементу исписка, возвращает итератор по результатам работы функции

list --- переведёт итератор в список

UPDATE:

lambda --- конструкия языка python для создания анонимных функций

```
# такая запись
lambda x: x[:-2]

# аналогична такой,
def f(x): 
    return x[:-2]
# с той лишь разницей, что не будет занято имя `f`
```

Comment: Если можете, объясните пожалуйста, что такое 'lambda'

Comment: Полагаю лучше отметить ответ DmitryErohin как верный. Использование list-comprehension является более pythonic way. Документация Python прямо говорит это это более ["кратко и понятно"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

Функция `map`, обходит все элементы списка и делает срез всех символов до последних двух из каждой строки:

```
res = map(lambda x: x[:-2], lst1)
print(list(res))
```